# How to turn off game notifications in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 today. I'm kinda liking it but every time I launch a game, it pops up some stupid notification, like "Use this keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot", or "Use this combo to open the Game Bar".

How can I make Windows 10 stop pestering me with things I don't want to do when I launch games?

[image: Starcraft 2 screen with Game Bar popup]

Comment: [Read this article](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/exploring-the-notifications-center-in-windows-10/) and it shows what notifications can be turned off and on. I've yet to install win 10 so it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Those aren't really the same thing. It's a grey box in the middle of the screen. I'll take a screeenshot when I next launch.

Comment: Heh. Microsoft is apparently trying to copy Steam here.

Comment: Is that launching it from the Xbox app? Or launching directly? Please tell me you don't get those launching a game from outside the xbox app. It's bad enough when I start a uplay game of steam and get two sets of popups.

Comment: That is direct launch, or launch through Steam/Battle.NET. I don't even know what the Xbox app is.

Comment: Yay for bloatware built into the OS!

Comment: @immibis Well, considering how so many reviews praise the xbox app for being one of the best parts of Windows 10 I think that for once it need not be considered bloatware (anymore).

Comment: When it interferes with the operation of my own games, it is bloatware.

Comment: @DavidMulder If an OEM bundled the exact same thing, it would universally be considered bloatware.

Comment: Go to a chatroom, guys. This isn't the place.

Comment: Oh, Microsoft. Oh dear oh dear.

Comment: There's an updated Q & A for this topic [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/how-to-toggle-game-bar-notifications-for-xbox-games-in-windows-10).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Apparently, you can open the game bar, and then one of the settings inside the game bar is "Stop pestering me with pointless stuff". If you don't want the Game Bar, gotta go in the Game Bar.

[image: "Show tips when I start a game", unchecked in the Settings]

Comment: You have to use the keyboard shortcut to open the bar, then click the gear icon.

Comment: I kind of hoped that was the actual name of the option.

Comment: Gotcha. For reference, it's win+g to do that. It only shows that tip sometimes, but I found it eventually.

Comment: It's the tip screenshotted in the question.

Comment: Could you add the hot key needed to bring this up (Win+G I believe it is)

Comment: How do you totally disable the gamebar entirely. The Win + G hotkey is still an issue for me.

Answer (score -4):

On your Windows 10 touch screen, swipe in from the right side of your display to open the Action Center.  Select All Settings, which opens the SYSTEM Settings Window.  Select Notifications & Actions, then either turn off "Show app notifications" or selectively turn off individual apps from the lower part of that window.

Comment: That won't turn off the notification shown in picture. It's not an "app notification".

Comment: Sad thing is, this is a truly useful answer and was exactly what I was looking for, just not to this specific question.

Answer (score -5):

Here's instructions how to disable it:

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8637-game-bar-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: You should probably include the information in that article in case the link goes down. Your answer won't be able to stand on two legs if that does happen.